# Youtube Request gets blocked

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I wanted to use the Android Youtube API for that i created
an API key in google console and added it to my project.
Now when i execute a Youtube Query i get the following message:

```
04-25 16:41:05.899: W/System.err(7213): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213): {
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):   "code" : 403,
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):   "errors" : [ {
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):     "domain" : "usageLimits",
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):     "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):     "reason" : "ipRefererBlocked",
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):     "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com"
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):   } ],
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213):   "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
04-25 16:41:05.900: W/System.err(7213): }
```

What else do i have to do to make google not blocking my request? The request
limit per user is 3000 per day and i used 0 of it.

Comment: This is likely a silly question, but you did add your originating IP to your API key in the developer's console, correct? The error message is not a quota one, but is instead about access control. This could also occur if you're running through a proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Google developer dashboard click on Credentials and see if your API key is set by referrer or by IP. If it's limited make sure it matches your referrer or IP.

[image: Public API access]

Comment: do you know how to check this features in the new google developer console web interfaces????

Comment: 1. Log into https://console.developers.google.com/project?pli=1
2. Click on your project.
3. Click on Enabled APIs tab.
4. Click YouTube Data API v3.
5. Click on Credentials in left pane.
6. Click on the credential you want to view in the right pane.

Comment: did you work with the new interfaces, google console has changed. In the new one this feature there isn't or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I just checked 6 mins ago and those were the steps taken in the new interface.

Comment: I want to create a simple key for Android but it doesn't show me the Referers. Only show API key, Activation data, Activated by... but not Referers.

Comment: Android keys do not use referrers. Perhaps you should ask a separate question.

Comment: I have the same above error but I am using an API key for Android. ok Thank you @johnh